# Почему через собачку @ доступны только кириллические ники?

Tags: дефект, комментарии, чат

Когда я набираю собачку (`@`), чтобы указать к кому я обращаюсь в комментариях к вопросу/ответу

[image: скриншот создания комментария]

или в чате, я вижу только кириллические ники

<sub>Это если что наш главный чат</sub>

[image: скриншот чата]

Comment: похоже на последних активных пользователей. как только начнешь набирать английскими буквами подсветит английские ники

Comment: @Grundy Кириллические сразу все высвечиваются после собачки, а латинские — нет. Выглядет как баг.

Comment: На самом деле не все. но скорее так и задумано

Comment: @Grundy Не понимаю, почему их нельзя сразу высвечивать. Если так и задумано, то это мягко говоря странная хрень:)

Comment: [Не только кириллические ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GAjm.png)

Comment: Возможно, дело в том, что латиница есть у всех и её набрать проще, а не латинские ники вполне может не быть даже раскладки на клавиатуре, поэтому они выводятся списком и можно выбрать табом.

Comment: @alexolut Странно, что нет кнопки ответить автору комментария как в мобильном приложении.

Comment: @Alex78191, в чате есть.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я не про чат